# email message with changing information

Tags: javascript, html, email, attr, mailto

I am trying to create email templates just using an html file. This file will display a list of mailto links that, when clicked, will open a template with message. I got it working for the most part but some of these templates use prompts to add information to the message before creating it. The problem is that it doesn't seem to work right. Here is my code.

```
function sendReport(emailName, addresseList){
    document.writeln('<a onClick="setPrompt(this,\'' + addresseList + '\')" href="mailto:' + addresseList + '?subject=' + 'Report' + '&body=' + 'Here is the report.' + '">' + emailName + '</a><br />');
}

function setPrompt(obj, addresseList){
    var reportName = prompt("Report name","");
    obj.attr('href', ='mailto:' + addresseList + '?subject=' + reportName + '&body=' + "Here is the report."); //<-- this is the line that is giving me trouble.
}
```

Comment: Remove the `=` from  `='mailto:'` in your last line. And it should be `obj.setAttribute(...)` if you are using Javascript without jQuery.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. You should add this as an answer so that I can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the last line and there is no `.attr()` built in function in Javascript. This should fix it:

```
obj.setAttribute('href', 'mailto:' + addresseList + '?subject=' + reportName + '&body=' + "Here is the report.");
```